# Does .NET Framework allow compiled applications to run without the need of its runtime?

Tags: .net, .net-core

.NET core allows its compiled applications to run without the need to install the runtime. All dependencies are packed together with the compiled exe. Can this be done with dotnet framework as well?

I'm trying to build an industrial application where the user does not need to install dotnet runtime as some computers do not have internet connection.

Comment: If you're building something from scratch: *don't use .NET Framework*; it is legacy and effectively obsolete - just jump straight to .NET Core or .NET 5 (which should be RTM probably before your app) - and use that, which *does* include this feature (btw, the answer to the specific question is "no, but there are some tools that try to do that, with varying degrees of success")

Comment: You can include .NET FW offline installer in your app, but .NET Core option is more preferable

Comment: A self-contained .netcore install is 61 MB minimum, the standalone .netframework installer is 80 MB.  The odds that the user needs to install the latter are low, it is pre-installed by Windows setup.

Comment: @HansPassant But the default version of FW that comes with Windows is 3.5, which is ancient even in .NET terms.

Comment: The Win7 end-of-life date was January 14th of this year.  Yay.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. Yeah I know .Net core is good but I'm actually stuck with a library which still hasn't be ported out to .Net Core yet

Answer (score -4):

.Net and .Net Core architecture requires you to have the runtime present on the system where the program is being executed. What you can do is pack your application and dependencies using an installer so that all dependancies including runtime will be installed on the client system with your application.

Comment: @IanKemp can you elaborate your comment?

Comment: .NET Core absolutely does not require a runtime installation. One of the improvements from Core over Framework is that you can ship the Core runtime **with your app** and it simply lives in the same directory. That means your app is completely self-contained and isolated from the state of the machine on which it's installed, which is a Very Good Thing.